# Keep visual studio from deleting everything from bin/ on rebuild?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a web application project. I have DLLs that I reference in the project stored in my bin/ folder. Well, whenever I do a rebuild or clean from Visual Studio, it will delete everything in that folder. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Because I have files like some assemblies for controls that are not owned by us and for Npgsql and AjaxControlToolkit and such.

Comment: If you add those assemblies from physical locations (eg C:\MyAssemblies\...), they will still be there. When you want to deploy your project to another machine, you need to register those assemblies on that machine (install them to the GAC) if they are not system assemblies.

Comment: Well, we are not wanting to have to register it with GAC..

Comment: The bin folder is intentioned as an output area for binaries from the projects you build. It is not strictly speaking the folder you bundle for deployment to clients. That really is a separate phase of the process. How do I justify this? Well if ANY dependency is in the GAC for example, VS will not output it to BIN folder. That means 3rd party GAC'd components won't get packaged.

Comment: I suggest one way to bundle specific DLLs is to add them to your project and mark them for output. This will automatically push them to the bin folder. Checking into the bin folder directly is contra to the architecture of VS build process and just doesn't make sense. Build agents for example customise this bin location. Build tools just don't expect the process you are implementing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll stay away from asking the 'why' question and just state the how.  Mark the files as read only and VS shouldn't delete them.

Comment: -1 only because you should not be storing your DLLs in the bin directory, even if there is a way to make it work.

Comment: That doesn't mean we should not answer the question.  Let's save the holier than thou for a place where debates like this are proper.

Comment: Actually I was more concerned with the fact that the answer was both accepted and the highest voted (at the time I downvoted it).  You are correct that it is a valid answer to the problem given.

Comment: Actually this can be a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so @JasonBerkan comment and [John Saunders' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2179972) *can* be on point.

Comment: @billb the question directly contradicts the design of VS build process and build variables. Bin folder is meant to be portable and is assumed to be by several components of MS tooling. As such, this is simply terrible practice and should not be encouraged. The OP should design their process to be inline with the tooling they are using.

Answer (score 53):

Do not put anything into bin yourself. bin is the target folder for binaries - it is not a source folder for binaries.

Create yourself a `lib` folder or something like that to put your third-party binaries into. You might even name it "Third Party Binaries", since not everyone knows that "lib" means the same thing. Make your references to the binaries in this folder, and Visual Studio will copy them into `bin` when necessary (including on a rebuild).

Comment: What about runtime dependencies that you don't reference directly (I only reference build-time dependencies) but are still needed to run the project?

Comment: @wen exact same thing - they don't belong in bin

Comment: @JohnSaunders True, but where do they belong? And how do they end up in the bin if you don't reference them. Or should one reference runtime dependencies too?

Comment: @wens referencing them is best

Answer (score 2):

Follow John Saunders answer and put your .dll's into a separate folder. In my case I named this folder "ServerAssemblies". Then modify your project file (.csproj in my case) and add an "AfterRebuild" target.

```
<Target Name="AfterRebuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExtraAssemblies Include="$(SolutionDir)ServerAssemblies\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ExtraAssemblies)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)bin\"></Copy>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain why you have to store it in the bin folder to begin with? i always create a separate folder for example /components where i store all referenced dll's.

Comment: idk, bin/ has always just made sense to me. It's the one place where executable binaries are placed. Will moving files out of bin/ cause problems?

Comment: @Earlz, you should have a lib directory (some people also like a thirdparty directory) where you place referenced assemblies. Your build script should copy these to the bin directory as required, this allows you to have a clean build.

Comment: @Paolo: Visual Studio will copy them to bin automatically if they are referenced from the `lib` folder.

Comment: @Earlz: another reason `bin` is not a good idea is that `bin` should never be checked into source control. It should be possible to restore all "source" files to do a clean build. That would never include your files in `bin`.

Comment: It's not like our generated binaries are in bin, bin/ is just has our third party assemblies. I see no problem with it.

Comment: Where are your generated binaries?

Comment: @Earlz - being able to do a clean build into an empty directory shows you have got all the components correctly rounded up and assembled, this helps enormously when it comes to packaging and deploying to another system (e.g. system test) as you won't be left chasing down that elusive "works on my machine" bug from the DLL you forgot to copy

Comment: @Paolo this is a very old question from when I was just starting with ASP.Net. Now I do things the "proper" way by having a `lib` directory

Answer (score -2):

One thing the "don't do it that way!" people are forgetting is source control and 3rd party software.  Using SVN you often get files that if physical references were used would create mismatches when they're not in the same physical location.

One CMS I'm working with at the moment prebuilds the VS project and solution when you set up another "instance" of it.  It dumps in some dlls it needs... but if you rebuild they vanish.

The simple solution in both cases is to do as stated above and call it done.