# Referencing file from bin directory in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is from a codebase that I have seen and I am not sure if it is good practice to do this.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Bin/Transactions/accounts.csv");
```

When the solution is compiled the `.csv` file is automatically copied to the bin folder, but is it bad practice to reference a physical file from the bin folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder `App_Data` would be a better choice, and recommended for such files.

More info on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the statement, .csv file is copied to the bin folder, pls check your project build properties has msbuild commands to copy the files to bin.

Regarding the question, yes it is bad to reference a physical file from the bin folder. Visual studio keeps deleting the bin folder on rebuild. Here is a similar post explaining the reasons.
[Keep visual studio from deleting everything from bin/ on rebuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179856/keep-visual-studio-from-deleting-everything-from-bin-on-rebuild)